# (Algorithm required) How to determine if a point is in one of many rectangles

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, search-trees

What I want to achive ist the following: I have a 2D plane and on this plane I will have a potentially large amount of rectangles (these are specified with 2 coordinates spanning it)

Whats the most efficient way to determine if a point is in one of the rectangles

From some previous research I found that quad trees are good for that and I think I also understand how they work but I can't figure out how they help to solve my problem. I can find points close to one point but how to I find out if my point is in one of the many rectangles?

Comment: Probably duplication of [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/63536/how-do-shapes-rectangles-work-in-quad-trees)?

Comment: Another potential duplicate is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254127/check-if-a-point-lies-inside-a-rectangle/19254680).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree#Generalization_for_higher_dimensions) or [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree).

Comment: Thanks for the response, but what are the benefits over a Quadtree (if there are any)

Comment: @derteufelqwe, those can be used to solve your problem; there are standard, well-documented explanations how to use them to solve your problem.  It sounds like you don't know how to use a quadtree to solve your problem (and I don't have anything in particular to propose, either).  Given those two facts, the benefit seems pretty clear!

Comment: Note for further readers: I ended up using quad trees as they are simpler IMO but this answer got me some good inspiration and contain also suitable solutions.